Set size for jenkins slaves via AWS EC2 plugin on Jenkins
I am trying to provision Jenkins slave instances on EC2 via the EC2 Plugin. However, on setting them up, I see that the default storage space for the spawned instance is always around 5 GB. Is there a way to increase storage volume from the plug in itself.
I tried playing around with the Block Device Mapping option But couldn't figure a way to increase the EBS volume. I can see the instances are allocated space on dev/nvme0n1p1. But could not increase its size.

I've had this exact question and couldn't find a way to do this with the plugin.
My solution was to create a new AMI based on the instance that was started by Jenkins, and specify a larger volume for that AMI. You can then use the AMI's ID in your cloud configuration in Jenkins.

You are looking at the right setting - to provision 100GB volume make the Block Device Mapping this:
/dev/nvme0n1p1=:100

I would double check the exact device name in the EC2 console.
